# A word to describe the feeling of liking something, without understanding why?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word that describes the feeling that you get when you enjoy or like something but you cannot put your finger on as to why you do?

Comment: If you are not satisfied with the answer, please mention why in the comments. If you are then accept it, so that the question is no longer shown as unanswered.

Comment: I agree with @Rio1210  though I'd add that there is no rush to accept unless one answer fits perfectly. Normally a few days is enough to get a range of answers and comments.

Comment: I think that a good analogy for what I'm thinking of is the word 'intuition'. Intuition can be defined as understanding something but not knowing how you got to understand it; the word I need is, instead, liking something but not knowing how you got to like it.

Comment: @user2909415 That comment helps clarify your question; I think worth editing question with that aspect.

Comment: In Spanish I would use *inexplicable*, and it works better there than in English.  It doesn't just mean unexplainable to others -- it also means unexplainable to yourself.  When I see this word it gives me the feeling of someone who is floating along in a stream containing mysterious feelings which he experiences but has little control or understanding of.  In English I like the proposed *ineffable*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you are asking for a word to describe something that you like but doesn't know why, but the word **ineffable** comes to my mind. It means something that you can't exactly put into words/describe.

According to Merriam Webster [Ineffable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ineffable) means:

- incapable of being expressed in words, indescribable. *An ineffable liking for something*.

If you insist on the part '*not knowing why*' or not knowing the '*reason behind the liking*'. I suggest the word **inexplicable**:

According to Merriam Webster [Inexplicable](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inexplicable) means:

- incapable of being explained, interpreted, or accounted for

For your case it might be something like: ***Inexplicable*** love/fondness for something.

The word **incomprehensible** might work in other contexts as well.

**EDIT:** P.S. I later noticed that you are looking for a single word. Well, if you are looking for a single word to express the 'total feeling' of *inexplicability* and the *liking*, then I guess this answer might come a bit short.

Comment: The problem with ineffable and inexplicable is that those words focus on not being to explain or describe this feeling; when, what I really need is to encapsulate the 'not understanding' part, which is why incomprehensible comes closer, but of course this doesn't encompass the 'liking' part.

Comment: I don't know of any single word that encapsulates both the part. This is how I would have done. You might want to wait out for a better answer from someone else. Thank you.